Help with application of Brouwer's fixed point theorem
Suppose that we have some continuous real-valued function $g(r)$ such that $g(0) = 0$. We consider $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $x = (x_1,\dots,x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Now assume that $R \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is some region and let $C(R)$ denote its convex hull.
For each $i$ we define $V_i : C(R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$V_i(x) = \int_R x_i g(r)/r dV$$as a function of the origin of the $x_i$ coordinates and $r = |x|$ (see article for more context but I would also appreciate some insight). We then define a vector field $V : C(R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ as $V(x) = V_1(x)e_1 + \dots + V_N(x)e_N$. The goal is to show that this vector field must vanish at some $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.
The reasoning starts with: If the origin is taken on the convex hull of $R$, the integral of $V_i$ is a mean value of the inward pointing vector $x_i$ with respect to the positive weight function $G(r)/r$.
Question: How is that so? I am not understanding anything of that phrasing.
The author proceeds with: "Hence, on the convex hull of $R$ the vector $V$ points inward.".
Question: How did he conclude that from the previous sentence?
Then we are supposed to use Brouwer's fixed point theorem but the version that I know is that for nonvanishing vector fields on balls, there are inward and outward pointing vector fields (so there must be a point where it vanishes?).
Question: I also understand that the convex hull is homeomorphic to a ball, so that part is alright but which version is he using?

You seem to be going back and forth between $N$ and $n$. Is $N = n$? Please use consistent notation!

@SammyBlack Yes, you are right. Corrected. Thank you for the remark.
